# Preview.app version 7 in macOS Sierra

Tags: applications, macos, image-editing

I have been using the Preview.app that comes with Mavericks until El Capitan.

The reason that I have been copying that application instead of using the newer version is that it works better for my workflow and for a lot of other people, such as [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6621306?tstart=0), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6637663), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2jjajx/yosemite_crippled_pdf_annotation_with_preview_any/).

I have been copying the version on every system upgrade without any problems but it seems this can't be done with Sierra.

[image]

Is there a way I can get this app to run on newer macOS Sierra or some other clone of this app I can use?

Console.app show this error:

```
Application failed to launch (id = com.apple.Preview, version = 7.0 reason = kLSIncompatibleApplicationVersionErr)
OSActivityID: 0x800000000034078c
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.launchservices.launchfailures.oldAppVersion
com.apple.message.signature: com.apple.Preview - 7.0
com.apple.message.result: failure
SenderMachUUID: C10E9E98-E1E0-3795-A40C-252F709E6C93
```

Comment: Try following: Open your programs folder. Choose preview.app and from the context menu (right click on the app) - choose **show package content**. Open the contents where you find info.plist. Open this file with Xcode for example. Change the entry **Minimum system version** to any earlier macOS Version for example the last system version that you work with preview. Save it an try whether works. Please make a backup before changes!

Comment: @dante12 Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't program in Obj-C, but I'm willing to bet that an error return of `kLSIncompatibleApplicationVersionErr` is not a barrier than can be overcome by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the old Preview and rename it (for example Preview_old), so you have two Previews in the Application folder. If the Preview_old gives the same failure and does not run, do the change as dante12 posted.
You have to change the GetInfo "open with" field to Preview_old for the relevant files.

Comment: /Applications/Preview_old.app/Contents/Info.plist has "LSMinimumSystemVersion" equals to 10.9.0 while the new app has 10.10.0. What should I put there? Thanks